# Не работает @Ajax.ActionLink asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

`@Ajax.ActionLink` работает как обычная ссылка, не могу найти причину проблемы...

BundleConfig:

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryuno").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));
......
```

И код во View:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Комментарии", "Comments", new { rev.Id },
            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Comments" })
```

Comment: Вы скрипт добавили в бандл, а отрендерить во view его случайно не забыли?

Comment: Стандартно выведено: @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

Comment: По описанию очень похоже на то, что скрипт не подгружается. Либо опишите детальнее

Comment: C BundleConfig в общем так и не разобрался, просто скрипты привизал к старинице.

Comment: Андрей, заранее буду благодарен за помощь. Как закончить строку  " comment.GuestbookReviewId" чтоб записывала ID страницы на которой размещена форма.

Comment: public ActionResult CommentCreate([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Message,DateAdded,GuestbookReviewId")] GuestbookComment comment)
        {
            comment.GuestbookReviewId = 
            comment.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            comment.GuestbookReviewId = 
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

Comment: Я, конечно, могу предположить что комментариев вряд ли будет много и предложить назначить автоинкрементное поле в базе типа int. Но я же не знаю какие у вас поля, как много комментариев вы ожидаете и что вы планируете с ними делать. Это уже другой вопрос получается.

Comment: Есть контент, к нему идут комментарии. Все это уже работает на тестовых данных. А вот форма добавления комментария, чтоб она привязывалась к ID контента сделать не могу. Примеры по Select уйма, весь инет именно примером Select усыпан. А так чтоб GuestbookReviewId автоматически генерировал ID страницы с который пишется комментарий найти не могу...

Answer (score 1):

У самого была такая проблема недавно - не мог подгрузить `AJAX` к `Razor`. Вот решение:

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            //AJAX
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ajax").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));

        }
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ajax")
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте, что в `Web.config` задан ключ **UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled** и установлен в **true**. Категория **appSettings**

> ```
> <appSettings>
>     <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
>   </appSettings>
> ```

2. Проверьте, что на страницу подключены следующие файлы скриптов:

   - jquery
   - jquery.unobtrusive-ajax

Сделать можно следующим образом:

1. Проверьте наличие файлов в связке, например

> ```
> bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jquery")
>                 .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js",
>                          "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
> ```

2. Проверьте подключение самой связки на страницу, например

> `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery")`

---

Если в папке `Scripts` не наблюдается данных файлов или вы создаете проект с нуля, то воспользуйтесь командой **`Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`**, которая установит необходимые пакеты вместе с зависимостями.